# Are Sparge Arms Necessary

Tags: techniques, sparge, wort, all-grain, efficiency

Do you really need a sprinkler of some sort to sparge?
Does it really improve the lautering process?
How fancy does a sparge arm need to be, does it really have to rotate or can it just sprinkle all over?

What are the cons of just having a piece of tubing adding sparge water to a 1-2 inch bed of water above the grains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually fly sparge. It consumes my attention, but shows that you do not need a sparge arm. My second-next equipment project will be a sparge arm (after a whirlpool chiller).

#### Does a sparge arm improve lautering?

[Yes](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Fly%5FSparging). If there were a quicker method that offered similar results the pro brewing community would have found it.

#### How fancy?

Not very.  My plan is to make a simple manifold out of PVC or copper that covers the top of my mash tun. I'll drill small holes in the material so sparge water flows out evenly.

#### Keep in mind:

Your primary concern in sparge arm design should be [channeling](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Channelling).  Ensure that the grainbed is evenly rinsed to gain the best efficiency.  Keep it simple.

Comment: I'd point out that just because the pro brewing community does or doesn't do something isn't necessarily a reason for homebrewers to do it or not. we have very different goals and brew on a very different scale with different equipment.  You can effectively fly sparge by simply laying a piece of tubing for your sparge water on top of your grain bed.  It wouldn't work for commercial brewers, but it works great for homebrewers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, no. But for me it's easier. I ordered the rotation sparge arm (got it for an incredible price...), and since the ammount of sparge water, etc, is dialed in perfectly after so many brews, I start the siphon when I know it's time, and walk away, and come back to a kettle with exactly what I should have, and so far I have had very little, if at all, problems with my OG, preboil and post.

Answer (score 0):

No, sparge arms are not necessary.